# Print amount of repeated numbers in array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, count, duplicates

I was wondering how to print the amount of repeated numbers from a randomly generated array with an array size of 10, and numbers from 1 - 10.

Example:
Array1: 1 7 6 5 6 7 8 10 9 8

Number of Patterns: 3

(Because it consists of; 2 six, 2 seven, 2 eights)

So far for my code I have done this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include "Source.h"
#include <algorithm>   
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    //START OF PROGRAM CODE\\

    //Declaritions\\

    const int ArraySize = 10;
    int arrayMain[ArraySize];
    int array1[ArraySize];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;


    //End of Declairations\\

    //Store Random Number in Array\\

    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
        arrayMain[i] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        array1[i] = arrayMain[i];  //Copy mainarray to array1


     }  

    for (j = 0; j != ArraySize; j++)
     {
        sort(array1, array1 + ArraySize); //Sort the array

     }


        //End of Store Random Number in Array\\
        //Program Output\\


    cout << "ArrayMain: " << arrayMain[0] << " " << arrayMain[1] << " " << arrayMain[2] << " " << arrayMain[3] << " " << arrayMain[4] << " " << arrayMain[5] << " " << arrayMain[6] << " " << arrayMain[7] << " " << arrayMain[8] << " " << arrayMain[9] << " " << endl;
    cout << "Array1: " << array1[0] << " " << array1[1] << " " << array1[2] << " " << array1[3] << " " << array1[4] << " " << array1[5] << " " << array1[6] << " " << array1[7] << " " << array1[8] << " " << array1[9] << " " << endl;
    //cout << "Number of Patterns: " << <DATA TO INPUT> << endl;

    //END OF PROGRAM CODE\\


}
```

Comment: Except for sorting, your code has not done much of counting.  If performance is not an issue, you could use a count map: for each entry in the array do countMap[entry]++, so the number of entries in the map with value higher than  1 is the number you're after.

Comment: Just use bucket sort.

Comment: If you allow the numbers to repeat, how generating just 10 numbers in the 1-10 range doesn't fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very simple pattern. You could use an array (I'll be using a vector) of a size equal to the range of possible random numbers

```
//creates a vector ArraySize big with all elements initialized to 0
std::vector<int> results(ArraySize, 0);
```

Then, go through your loop and use the random numbers as indexes and increment the values

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  results[(rand() % 10)]++;
```

Finally, to count how many patterns there are

```
std::cout << "Number of patterns: ";
std::cout << std::count_if(results.begin(), results.end(), [](int i){return i > 1;});
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: The map I mentioned in my comment to the question is the general case of this answer.  For numbers from 1 to 10, this answer is better.